# Drawing Image on canvases shows only the last draw

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have built a function which draws given image on given canvas.
From some reason it draws only the last image.
I get the labels in both of my canvas.
Tried to change self.imgGrayscale to imgGrayscale but it doesn't draws at all

```
self.DrawOnCanvas(self.img,self.canvas1)
self.DrawOnCanvas(HistoImage,self.canvas2)

def DrawOnCanvas(self,getImg,canvas):
        imgGrayscale = Image.fromarray(array(getImg)).resize((self.w1+2,self.h1+2))
        self.imgGrayscale = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgGrayscale)
        canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.imgGrayscale, anchor="nw") 
        widget = Tkinter.Label(self, text='Original Image', fg='white', bg='black')
        canvas.create_window(self.w1/2, self.h1/10, window=widget)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

The solution:

```
 self.draws=[]
 self.DrawOnCanvas(imgUni,self.canvas5,HistoLUT,self.canvas6,'Lambda Transformation')   

    def DrawOnCanvas(self,getImg,canvas):
        imgGrayscale = Image.fromarray(array(getImg)).resize((self.w1+2,self.h1+2))
        self.draws.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgGrayscale))
        canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.draws[-1], anchor="nw")
```

Comment: "...draws only the last image". This is often a sign of reassigning an image variable before giving each individual image time to load.  The common cures are (1) don't reuse a single image variable to hold multiple images--give each image it's own variable, or (2) give each image time to load by using the Image.onload method with a callback.

Comment: you are creating a local variable named `imgGrayscale`, but you're referencing an image name `self.imgGrayscale`. Is that a typo, or is that what your real code is doing? Also, since `DrawOnCanvas` is always drawing to the same coordinates, how do you know it's only drawing the last image, and not drawing all images on top of each other?

Comment: @markE I tried to add time.sleep for several seconds it didn't helped

Comment: @BryanOakley they are the same coordinates but I have different canvases.
I can't chnage "self.imgGrayscale to imgGrayscale otherwise it won't draw.
I don't know why but I think its the problem

Comment: @DimaB: my bad. I failed to see how you defined both `imgGrayscale` and then `self.imgGrayscale`.

Comment: @DimaB: `sleep` won't work. You will have to use one of the techniques in my previous comment. I don't know tkinker so I can't code you an example solution.

Comment: @markE do u have exmaple for the Image.onload?
coulnd't google good one

Comment: self.imgGrayscale is required because variables declared in a function are garbage collected once the function exits, i.e. imgGrayscale disappears, but self.imgGrayscale is a class attribute so remains as long as the class remains.  So you are probably pointing to the last image only with self.imageGrayscale.  Add a list to keep them all in

Comment: @CurlyJoe Thanks! made a list and it works great.
I defined global list:
self.draws=[]
and changed the function:
        def DrawOnCanvas(self,getImg,canvas):
            #drawImage on top canvas
            imgGrayscale = Image.fromarray(array(getImg)).resize((self.w1+2,self.h1+2))
            self.draws.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgGrayscale))
            canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.draws[-1], anchor="nw")